# Window content freezes

Tags: debian, xorg, kde, window-manager, freeze

I recently started using Kanotix, a Debian based distro that loads itself into RAM on boot, and i'm loving it. But this is the second time I have this problem, and I was wondering what caused it and how to fix it.

So it boots up and KDE works perfectly, but for some reason the content of windows freeze up. It kind of looks like you're screen that split second before a BSOD.

Everything inside the window still works, I can still type and everything. When I minimize and restore a window enough times, it will show the actual content.

I can switch between desktops and all effects work perfectly. Restarting the X server doesn't do anything.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
result of free

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8175584    1801436    6374148          0      77632     408004
-/+ buffers/cache:    1315800    6859784
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: Sounds vaguely like the driver for your display xard is buggy. Try a different driver and/or a lower resolution.

Comment: I have an Ati Radeon HD5830, and i have the catalyst control center installed. Are there any other possibilities for this card? Because if i remember correctly, i spent hours finding and installing this one...

Comment: (1) When it happen, do `free` and see how much ram is left. (2) How much ram you have? (3) Did you configure swap partition?

Comment: @JohnSiu (1)updated with result of free, (2)I have 8 GB of RAM, (3)I did not manually, but i think that it was done at installation(?) not sure about this, I'm still a bit of a newb at the "behind the scenes" working of Linux/Unix

Comment: The symptom match when running out of memory. However you have planty of free ram. I am clueless now.

Comment: Oh well, thanks anyways. Could you upvote the question please, maybe i'll get an answer faster then

Comment: Latest version of your distribution? It might be a bug that has already been solved.

Comment: Try create a new user and see if the problem occur.